# How to check and get different part of a string

Tags: php

I'm looking to have it so someone does !whisper EXAMPLE this is a test example.

It would output 
`$whisperuser` as "EXAMPLE" & `$whispermessage` as "this is a test example".

```
<?php
    if (strpos($message, '!whisper') === 0) {
        $arr = explode(' ',trim($message));
        $whisperuser = $arr[1]; 
        $whispermessage = $arr[2]; // I need Whisper message to be anything arr[2] and HIGHER. 
        // WOULD DO OUTPUT STUFF HERE
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be written easy. After adding the 3rd argument to explode, it will put the rest of a string to the last item

```
list( , $whisperuser, $whispermessage) = explode(' ',trim($message), 3);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/583948)

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match for that. *Assuming that user can't have space in name*

```
$str = '!whisper EXAMPLE this is a test example';

$matches = [];

preg_match("/!whisper\s(\w+)\s(.*)$/", $str, $matches);

if (!empty($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[2])) {
    echo "Wispering to user {$matches[1]}: '{$matches[2]}'";
} else {
    echo "No actions taken!";
}
```

[PHP Snippet](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c2fca0019f6ed4a84cc5646739e5813bf965446) and [RegEx example](https://regex101.com/r/gN0nC3/1)

---

*IF* user can have space in name, than you must somehow specify where it's name ends. Because with your example whispering to `some user new` would be impossible if there is user `some user`.